# how is the module called "nodesnap" used with Express and Nodejs?

Tags: nodes

Getting confused with what the module called "nodesnap" exactly does when being used with Express and Nodejs ?

Note: Providing a link explaining how to use "nodesnap" module in detail other than this link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodesnap is much appreciated if it is available.

```
Thanks in advance.
```

Answer (score 0):

nodesnap is asynchronus event processor, it follows FSM (Finite state machine) approach to execute the tasks.

For ex: if a task has 5 steps(step-1...step-5), you will define them in five states.